# Gnu screen: get around 100-character limit for commands - can't change hardstatus

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a hardstatus line set in my .screenrc file:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline '%{= kg}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= kB}%?%-Lw%?%{+b r}(%{G}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{-b B}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}%]'
# This is 127 characters
```

I routinely log in to remote servers that are shared with other users who have their own favourite hardstatus line. I want to change the hardstatus for my screen session by entering it as a command after starting the session. Unfortunately, screen stops accepting input for the command after reaching around 100 characters.

When I talk about screen commands, I mean the ones entered after tying <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd>

Is there a way to increase the screen command character limit beyond 100 characters, or another way to set the hardstatus without altering the .screenrc file? A solution for changing it after the session is started would be preferred, but a command line option when starting screen would be a good alternative if it's possible.

One way to work around the problem would be put the hardstatus line in a file and enter <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> `:source <file>`, or type this after starting screen:

```
screen -p <SESSION_NAME or PID> -X hardstatus alwayslastline '%{= kg}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= kB}%?%-Lw%?%{+b r}(%{G}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{-b B}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}%]'
```

But I'd really like to know how to increase the character limit for commands.

Thanks in advance,

Matthew

Comment: I'm curious why multiple interactive users are sharing a single user account on a system. Such would seem like a security / auditing nightmare. And if that assumption is incorrect, I would ask why you can't modify your ~/.screenrc - Mostly since fixing an issue like this is the specific purpose of that file. Just trying to make sure this isn't an XY problem.

Comment: There is one user account with the correct environment for running certain jobs. Company policies and processes restrict access to this system, so we can't create additional accounts on it. I could modify the .screenrc file, but someone else set it to his preferences before I started using the system and it would be mean to change it on him. Still, none of this has to do with the restriction on 100 character commands, which is what I'd really like to know how to change. Thanks for the interest though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; the 100 char limit is hardcoded (I think the upper limit is enforced in [screen/src/input.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/input.c#n137), but function callers may provide a shorter buffer to begin with, so that's potentially not the only place that would need patching).

As a less typing-intensive solution, I recommend adding a `.screenrc-DarthAndroid` that first calls `source .screenrc` and then adds your preferred override settings; then, create a shell alias `myscr="screen -c ~/.screenrc-DarthAndroid "`.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for the 100 char limit explanation about the behaviour. As for the second paragraph, I can accomplish this just using a .screenrc file (optionally naming it something else). Thanks for solving the mystery :)